# Android BaseAdapter dont loop to view all Array items

Tags: android, listview

i'm using `BaseAdapter` for fill items into ListView, but my BaseAdapter class only show one item of ArrayList. for example i'm fill array list with this code:

```
private static ArrayList<SubCategoriesList> category_items;
...

SubCategoriesList cList = new SubCategoriesList();
cList.id = 0;
cList.users = "1";
cList.group_name = "Group one";
category_items.add(cList);

SubCategoriesList cListA = new SubCategoriesList();
cListA.id = 1;
cListA.users = "2";
cList.group_name = "Group two";
category_items.add(cListA);
```

`category_items.size()` in this phase is 2. and i'm expect my listview have 2 row by this code:

```
adapter = new AdapterCategoriesList(G.context, category_items);
uiFiller.lv_main_sub_category_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

AdapterCategoriesList adapter :

```
public class AdapterCategoriesList extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SubCategoriesList> categoryArrayList;
    private Object mLock = new Object();

    public AdapterCategoriesList(ArrayList<SubCategoriesList> array) {
        categoryArrayList = array;
    }

    public AdapterCategoriesList(Context context, ArrayList<SubCategoriesList> array) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        categoryArrayList = array;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categoryArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public SubCategoriesList getItem(int position) {
        return categoryArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main_categories_list_item, null);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        SubCategoriesList item = getItem(position);
        mViewHolder.fillItems(this, item, position);

        return convertView;
    }

    // Java Reflection UI Handler
    private static class UiFiller extends HelperUI {
        public TextView tv_item_category_users;
        public UiFiller(View view) {
            parseUi(view);
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private UiFiller uiFiller;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            uiFiller = new UiFiller(view);
        }

        public void fillItems(final AdapterCategoriesList adapter, final SubCategoriesList item, final int position) {
            uiFiller.tv_item_category_title.setText(item.getGroup_name() + "(" + item.getUsers() + ")");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare all code proper! like, not declare code for  "HelperUI" class ?

Comment: added answer did it worked for you

Comment: @apk problem is `getView` but i can not solved now

Comment: @apk yeah sir. i get null exception

Comment: private ArrayList<SubCategoriesList> categoryArrayList = new ArrayList<SubCategoriesList>(); did this?

Comment: @apk problem solved. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30164979/4790312

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it's working now

```
category_items=new ArrayList<SubCategoriesList>();
category_items.add(new SubCategoriesList("1"));
category_items.add(new SubCategoriesList("2"));

adapter = new AdapterCategoriesList(G.context, category_items);
uiFiller.lv_main_sub_category_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The model class

```
public class SubCategoriesList {

    String user;

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public  String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public SubCategoriesList(String user) {
        this.user=user;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
```

if you want a very fast solution (and a bit dirty :D ) solution try:

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: not any change sir. after change that i have only one item in listview

Answer (score -1):

solved problem. my ListView parent was ScrollView and after remove that. my problem solved. adapter was correct